# Setting up JDK containing only javac

Tags: java, javac

Is it possible to set up the JDK with only `javac` in a reliable way, without removing and adding components until it runs (trial and error)?

In my usecase I would like to create a Linux based Docker image which contains multiple `javac` versions and then use a volume to provide the source files to compile and one to retrieve the compiled class files. The container should only be able compile Java classes, nothing else.
Installing the JDK packages from the package repository of the Linux distribution and downloading ones which are not available as package manually from https://jdk.java.net/archive/ is definitely an option, but they are quite large (~ 190MB each version) and contain duplicate content and content not needed for compiling.

I have noticed that the `jmods/jdk.compiler.jmod` contains `javac` in the `bin` folder. Extracting it and executing it failed due to missing libraries so I tried merging its contents with the modules marked as required in the `module-info`:

- `java.base`
- `java.compiler`

However, when I then tried to run `javac` I got:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   Failed setting boot class path.

Any hints in the right direction are appreciated.

Comment: You also need all dependencies of the file to be compiled.

Comment: Could try `jlink --add-modules java.se,jdk.compiler --output ...` and then copy `javac` over to the generated image's `bin` directory.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, I haven't thought much about dependencies yet because it is mainly for comparing compiler output so there will likely be no (or few) dependencies only and I guess those could be provided using a volume as well.

Comment: @Slaw, yes that worked! Note that I only used `jdk.compiler` as module and that also copied `javac` to the runtime image on its own. With `--compress=2` (ZIP compression) this required a total of 45 MB for JDK 13 which is way better. Do you want to add that as answer?

Comment: Could possibly use `--strip-debug` to make it even smaller.

Comment: @Slaw good point. However it fails if `objcopy` is not installed (see https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/351), but you can use `--strip-java-debug-attributes` which does not require that library. And you can even further reduce the size using `--no-header-files` and `--no-man-pages` which reduced the size for me to 42 MB.
So do you want to write the answer since you gave me now twice valuable hints?

Comment: As you're the one who managed to make it work, and know exactly what you did to make it work, I think an answer from you would be more beneficial to any future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JDK versions >= 9 one can use the [`jlink`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jlink.html) tool:

```
jlink --add-modules jdk.compiler --output my-path
```

This creates a custom runtime image (here in the directory `my-path`) containing the needed libraries and the binary file `bin/javac`. Note however that this way most of the modules which are part of [`java.se`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.se/module-summary.html) (e.g. SQL, XML and Desktop classes) are not present and must be provided when invoking `javac`.

The size of the runtime image can be further reduced using the following plugins:

- `--compress=2`: Use ZIP compression
- `--no-header-files`: Excludes header files
- `--no-man-pages`: Excludes man pages
- `--strip-debug`: Strips debug information, includes the options (which can be set separately since JDK 13):

  - `--strip-java-debug-attributes`: Strips debug information from Java class files
  - `--strip-native-debug-symbols` (Linux only, requires `objcopy`): Strips debug symbols from executables and shared libraries
- `--vm=server`: Only include server JVM

(Use `jlink --list-plugins` to see all available plugins)

For JDK 13 which is roughly 190 MB large, this created a folder whose contents are only 42 MB in total.